# Excel: Subtotaling via changes in two different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

First question here. I'm a competent enough programmer but I'm wondering if there's an excel-like way to solve this. Lets say I have three columns: account #, date, expenditure. I want to see each accounts' expenditure via year. If I wanted to just see the gross total for all years per account, I know I could use the subtotal option. However, there doesn't seem to be an option to differentiate on more than one column (unlike the 'sort' function). What does SU recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate on more than one column in Excel. To do this, check each of your column names in the below window (under "Add subtotal to:"):

[image]